# Turtle Graphics APK

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, python-turtle, python-for-android

I have built a snake game using Turtle graphics module of Python, and now I wish to convert it into an apk.

I have tried `kivy`. It builds the apk, but the app crashes as soon as I open it in android. When using `adb logact -s python`, it says that the tkinter module is not available.

On further researching, I got to know that turtle graphics is based upon tkinter module and tkinter is not supported by `python-for-android`. The solutions suggest to rewrite my code in Kivy, but I don't know how to do so.

Any suggestions on how can I run my turtle graphics game on android?

Answer (score 0):

> The solutions suggest to rewrite my code in Kivy, but I don't know how to do so.

> Any suggestions on how can I run my turtle graphics game on android?

It looks like you've already found the solution: rewrite your graphics in Kivy, or another python module that works on android. Recent pygame releases might.

If you don't know how to do so, you need to learn. If you try to do so but have problems with any specific question, that would be a better target for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Due to some specific constraints, I need to use the Turtle graphics module, but I'll surely look into ```pygame``` as you suggested. Thanks for the suggestion!